# Загрузка нескольких фото PHP

Tags: php, html

Ситуация такая, могу загружать по одному фото, но потребовалось сделать загрузку нескольких, решил написать отдельную функцию, но что то запутался. Код при загрузке 1 файла

```
// Проверка, загружено изображение или нет
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
    // Если загружено, переместить его в нужную папку
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/images/products/{$id}.jpg");
}
```

html код

```
<input type="file" name="image" placeholder="" value="">
```

Для загрузки нескольких фото создал отдельную функцию, код ниже

```
public static function UploadPhoto($id)
{       
    $file_count = count($_FILES["image"]);
    $file_keys = array_keys($_FILES["image"]);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
            // Если загружалось, переместим его в нужную папке, дадим новое имя
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/images/products/{$id}_{$i}.jpg");
        }    
    }
}
```

вызываю функцию `upl::UploadPhoto($id);`

изменил html код

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" placeholder="" value="">
<input type="file" name="image[]" placeholder="" value="">
```

Мое видение ситуации -> нужно создать массив image, передать туда все загруженные файлы, передать этот массив функции, в функции получить количество загруженных файлов, переместить файлы в нужную директорию. По коду думаю что ошибка в функции том месте, где идет обращение к глобальному массиву $_FILES, подскажите как правильно сделать

Comment: А в чём проблема то?

Comment: Что то не верно и не работает код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во первых**, массив файлов хранится так.

```
array(1) images {
    [tmp_name] => [
        [0] => /file1.tmp
        [1] => /file2.tmp
        [2] => /file1.tmp 
    ]
    [name] => [
        [0] => /file1.jpg
        [1] => /file2.png
        [2] => /file1.gif
    ]
    ...
}
```

А значит это :

> $file_count = count($_FILES["image"]);

Нужно написать так :

```
$file_count = count($_FILES["image"]['name']);
```

А значит обработка массива будет другая.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $file_count;$i++){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'][$i]['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/images/products/{$id}_{$i}.jpg"
}
```

**Во вторых**, не обязательно в HTML добавлять два поля. Достаточно указать в *name* массив.

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" placeholder="" value="">
```

**P.S.** Советую проверять $_FILES['image'][$i]['type'] и сохранять нужный формат, ибо сохранять gif в jpeg не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 - появилась ошибка, но теперь он понимает сколько фото я загрузил, т.е. если я вставил 3 фото, он отображает 3 ошибки  и.т.д , ошибка в цикле for где $_FILES['image'][$i]

Comment: Вы немного ошиблись, идентификатор должен быть после ['tmp_name'] -> $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]

Comment: @veti4 , верно, прошу прощения.